# Distance covered by wheels and the angle it turns by (physics and robotics)

Tags: c, rotation, physics, robotics, webots

Let me try and describe what I'm working on.

I'm trying to code the controller for a vacuum cleaning robot. The entire project is done within the Webots platform. How it works is that when the robot hits a wall, it turns by a random angle and continues cleaning the house.

The issue: what I found was that the amount it turns by is inaccurate. If I specify for it to turn by 90 degrees, it only turns by 60. If I specify for it to turn by 360 degrees, it only turns by 240 or so (visual guesstimation).

I found a workaround - a temporary workaround. I found that multiplying the angle by a certain amount (1.2275) will turn the angle very close to the real angle specified in the question. So if I specify the angle to turn as 180, and multiply that with 1.2275, I get a value that is probably 175 or 177 (again from visual guesstimation).

The problem is that this error stacks up over time. So initially it might be an offset of just 2-3 degrees, which is nothing, but over 30 minutes of running the simulation it might build to relatively high numbers. This is unacceptable.

I asked a friend and he suggested that I scale the offset as the simulation progresses so that the offset scales with the error, but I feel this is a temporary workaround.

I would appreciate some help with the physics of it all as I don't really understand or know much about the mechanical field it works in. Any help would be appreciated.

Provided below is the code for the turn function.

```
static void turn(double angle) {
    double l_offset = wb_position_sensor_get_value(left_position_sensor);
    double r_offset = wb_position_sensor_get_value(right_position_sensor);
    double orient;

    stop();

    angle = angle * ANGLE_OFFSET;   //the important part
    double neg = (angle < 0.0) ? -1.0 : 1.0;

    step();

    wb_motor_set_velocity(left_motor,   neg * HALF_SPEED);
    wb_motor_set_velocity(right_motor, -neg * HALF_SPEED);

    do {
        double l  = wb_position_sensor_get_value(left_position_sensor) - l_offset;
        double r  = wb_position_sensor_get_value(right_position_sensor) - r_offset;
        double dl = l * WHEEL_RADIUS;  // distance covered by left wheel in meter
        double dr = r * WHEEL_RADIUS;  // distance covered by right wheel in meter

        orient = neg * (dl - dr) / AXLE_LENGTH; // delta orientation in radian

        step();
    } while (orient < neg * angle);

    stop();
    step();
}
```

Let me provide some explanation for the code. `angle` obviously specifies the angle to turn the robot by.  The second line shows the workaround that I'm currently using. Reading through the next few lines you can see that the robot turns by moving the left wheel backwards, and the right wheel forwards. It continuously gets the distance covered by the wheels and checks for a condition. When that condition is true, it stops turning.

My guess is that there might be something wrong in `orient = neg * (dl - dr) / AXLE_LENGTH; // delta orientation in radian` this line. Any tips? Maybe someone who can verify if the physics/mechanics aspect of it is correct?

Comment: is your sample period infinite?

Comment: @stark it essentially is infinite, yeah. The robot does 100s of turns in any proper test period.

Comment: What happens in simpler tests, when you run both motors at the same speed? Does the robot move linearly and keep its orientation? Does it move a distance `l * WHEEL_RADIUS`?

Comment: What's the timestep of the `step()` function, i.e. for how long will the motors turn at the specified velocities with each call?

Answer (score 0):

Can you segment the cause of the discrepancy between the desired angle and the actual (visual) angle?  I seems diving in and fixing that would be a better use of time than patching a patch.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? I don't quite understand. 

If you mean adjusting the offset, I tried that. I went to 6 decimal places and an increase part this point would overadjust (this value hits slightly lesser than specified angle). I can't seem to be able to find the middle point where it "just works".

Comment: I just mean, why is an offset necessary?  Is there something non-ideal in your mechanics?  Gears?  Calculations?

Comment: Riight. I tried looking into the gears but I couldn't see anything wrong the first time. I'll look into it again. I'm not really sure about the mechanics since I'm working with someone else's code but I'll try to look into that. I guess the main issue is that my work doesn't really focus on the mechanics/physics part of it but a 'logic' part. Maybe there's some issue with some of the values. I'll see what I can do